# eo-yaml: remove item from YamlSequence

Tags: java, yaml

```
        final YamlMapping original = Yaml.createYamlMappingBuilder()
                .add(
                        "some_key",
                        Yaml.createYamlSequenceBuilder().add("one").add("two").build()
                )
                .build();

        final YamlMapping updated = new MergedYamlMapping(
                original,
                () -> Yaml.createYamlMappingBuilder()
                        .add(
                                "some_key",
                                Yaml.createYamlSequenceBuilder().add("three").add("four").build()
                        ).build(),
                true
        );

        System.out.println(updated);
```

prints:

```
some_key:
  - one
  - two
  - three
  - four
```

I'm using https://github.com/decorators-squad/eo-yaml.  I'd like to replace a `YamlSequence`, but the old elements are not removed, even when `overrideConflicts=true`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The [code of `MergedYamlMapping`](https://github.com/decorators-squad/eo-yaml/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amihaiemil/eoyaml/extensions/MergedYamlMapping.java#L183) handles `YamlMapping` values different than simple values. It applies the override to their children, not to the values themselves.
As you create `YamlSequence`s their content is always merged.

If you want to overwrite the values I you have to use a `MutableYamlMappingBuilder` instead.